# "object Object" response in Google Floodlight custom variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, double-click-advertising, google-floodlight

I am utilizing the Google Tag Manager javascript variable to pass through a custom array into a Floodlight pixel u-variable. Within GTM preview, the array is populating correctly. However, my floodlight custom variable reporting returns a [object Object] value and not the array.

Two questions:

1. What is the reason for the "object Object" value response?
2. Is passing an array into a custom variable not allowable?

Thanks in advance to the community for the help.

GTM Variable:
order_item_data.items

[image: From Chrome console]

Here is the GTM response. My variable is populating correctly.
[image]

Comment: your code (which you haven't shared) is treating an object as if it were a string perhaps? `({}).toString()` where `({})` is any Object, results in the string `[object Object]`

Comment: Thanks for input as this helped me understand the root issue and lead to my solution. Solution: write a custom javascript function using the JSON.stringify method.                    
 function() {
  var orderString = JSON.stringify(order_item_data.items[1]);
  return orderString
}